# remove all quotation marks when writing to a txt file

Tags: python

Im writing the list deck into a file, however i need each item in each list to not have ' ' around it when written in.

```
deck = [['ad','ah','ac','as'],['2d','2h','2c','2s'],['3d','3h','3c','3s'],['4d','4h','4c','4s'],['5d','5h','5c','5s'],['6d','6h','6c','6s'],['7d','7h','7c','7s'],['8d','8h','8c','8s'],['9d','9h','9c','9s'],['td','th','tc','ts'],['jd','jh','jc','js'],['qd','qh','qc','qs'],['kd','kh','kc','ks']]

f = open('list.txt','w')
for i in deck:
    a=str(i)[1:-1].strip("'")+"\n"
    f.writelines(a)
f.close()
```

As seen in the code above ive tried to use .strip() but that isnt working as its only removing the first and last quotation. Would there be a way to get the text file to look like this:

```
ad, ah, ac, as
2d, 2h, 2c, 2s
3d, 3h, 3c, 3s
4d, 4h, 4c, 4s
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `join` to join the different parts of each sublist with `', '`:

```
deck = [['ad','ah','ac','as'],['2d','2h','2c','2s'],['3d','3h','3c','3s'],['4d','4h','4c','4s'],['5d','5h','5c','5s'],['6d','6h','6c','6s'],['7d','7h','7c','7s'],['8d','8h','8c','8s'],['9d','9h','9c','9s'],['td','th','tc','ts'],['jd','jh','jc','js'],['qd','qh','qc','qs'],['kd','kh','kc','ks']]

with open('list.txt','w') as f:
    for sublist in deck:
        f.write(', '.join(sublist)+'\n')
```

Output (in `list.txt`):

```
ad, ah, ac, as
2d, 2h, 2c, 2s
3d, 3h, 3c, 3s
...
```

Also, note that it is better to use `with open...` to make sure that your file gets closed whatever happens.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `.replace("'", "")` instead of `.strip("'")`. Strip only removes the characters from the left and right side of the string and not in the middle, which is why you see the array being printed as `ad', 'ah', 'ac', 'as` on each line:

```
deck = [['ad','ah','ac','as'],['2d','2h','2c','2s'],['3d','3h','3c','3s'],['4d','4h','4c','4s'],['5d','5h','5c','5s'],['6d','6h','6c','6s'],['7d','7h','7c','7s'],['8d','8h','8c','8s'],['9d','9h','9c','9s'],['td','th','tc','ts'],['jd','jh','jc','js'],['qd','qh','qc','qs'],['kd','kh','kc','ks']]

f = open('list.txt','w')
for i in deck:
    a=str(i)[1:-1].replace("'", "")+"\n"
    f.writelines(a)
f.close()
```

[Repel.it Example](https://repl.it/repls/BlondCreepyUpgrades)

Answer (score 1):

You can work along the lines of this:

```
for each in deck:
  for INDEX, EACH in enumerate(each):
    if INDEX==0:
      print(EACH,end='')
    else:
      print(','+EACH,end='')
  print('\n')
```

Producing the output:

```
ad,ah,ac,as

2d,2h,2c,2s

3d,3h,3c,3s

4d,4h,4c,4s

...
```

Answer (score 1):

What you try to perform is to write in [csv fromat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). Namely try something like this:

```
import csv


with open('list.txt','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    writer.writerows(deck)
```